# How to store data on a pivot table with eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I am trying to store a "project" with its respective categories. the categories are already defined in the category table.
in category_project pivot table I have category_id and project_id.

I have been able to get the category_id, but not the Project_id - When I submit the create form

Laravel throws me an error saying that the project_id field cannot be null. but I don't know how to get that project_id together with the category_id

```
 ::::CONTROLLER - ProjectController.php

 $project = new Project();
 $project->title = request('title');
 $project->client = request('client');
 $project->description = request('description');
 $project->year = request('year');
 $project->categories()->sync($request->categories);
 $project->tools()->sync($request->tools);
 $project->save();
```

```
::::MODEL - Category.php

class category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name' ,
    ];
    public function projects(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
    }
}
```

```
::: MODEL - Project.php

class project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title' ,
        'client' ,
        'description',
        'year',
     
    ];

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
    public function tools(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tool::class);
    }
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class);
    }
}
```

```
::: VIEW - CreateProject.blade.php (Only select)
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Categorías</label>
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" name="categories[]">
  @foreach($categories as $key => $value)
      <option value='{{ $key }}'>{{ $value }}</option>
     @endforeach
                              
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: as your previous question about the same thing ... you need to save the project before you can use the relationship to sync the data

Comment: here `$project->categories()` it code means create category with `$project->id` so `project_id` should automatically filled, the issue may be you are using `P` capital `Project_id ` to `project_id`

Answer (score 0):

I modified...

```
   $project = new Project();
    $project->title = request('title');
    $project->client = request('client');
    $project->description = request('description');
    $project->year = request('year');
    
    $project->save(); // first, save de project
    $project->categories()->attach($request['categories']);
    $project->tools()->attach($request['tools']);
```